Is CSS making the content of my page slide in from the left to the right upon rendering?
When my Wordpress page at https://www.twerskitorah.com/ renders, it doesn't just appear on the page.  Instead it kind of slides in from the left to the right and I want to stop this.  I've looked for 'transition:' in several places and can't seem to locate where this should be changed. Is CSS causing this?  How can I turn it off?
This site uses the generatepress theme and the pagelayer plugin.
I have added transition: none; to the html section of the all.css file but the content still slides in
I have added this code to combined.css  in pageplayer and the problem persists.  I am not sure where to look or where to put the 'none' directive.
Thank you!

It's pagelayer jQuery code in combined.js

Please read Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Ideally you’d be able to take out all the animation from the JavaScipt and have the final values right in the CSS, but if you’re looking for a quick fix before shabbos, it looks like the transition is being set on the [pagelayer-id] selector.
[pagelayer-id] {
  transition: none;
}

Assuming your authored CSS comes after the theme-provided CSS, that should work. If not, you may have to hack it with !important (unless you can refactor the whole thing with @layers).

Absolutely before Shabbos!  :)
The authored CSS does come from the theme's CSS.  Your suggestion made it less 'slidey' but it still doesn't just appear like this page from the site
https://www.twerskitorah.com/sermons/
That one just opens.

That may be unavoidable in the short term, unfortunately. It seems like there’s some other silly stuff the theme author did with JS overriding things about the layout to make the animation work, so without going through and digging all of that out, you may be left with that brief flicker.

Also, it looks like you accidentally added some CSS in the wrong place because it’s showing up at the top of the site.

Oh yeah - I guess I did!  Thank you for letting me know and thanks for helping.
